# Yii 2, при message/extract, все поля message.translation NULL

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток. Или чего то не понимаю, или что то не так... Помогите, пожалуйста.

Необходимо что бы переводы работали через БД - Yii::t('app', 'No')

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-dbmessagesource.html

есть две таблицы message и source_message штатной структуры, в которые помещаются результаты распаковки.

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('source_message', [
        'id' => 'INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'category' => 'VARCHAR(32)',
        'message' => 'TEXT',
        'PRIMARY KEY (id)',
    ]);
    $this->createTable('message', [
        'id' => 'INT(11)',
        'language' => 'VARCHAR(16)',
        'translation' => 'TEXT',
        'PRIMARY KEY (id,language)',
    ]);

    $this->addForeignKey('fk_message_source_message', 'message', 'id', 'source_message', 'id','CASCADE','RESTRICT');
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('source_message');
    $this->dropTable('message');
}
```

конфигурация командой

```
    yii message/config-template @app/config/messages.php
```

файл конфигурации https://pastebin.com/P6rTCNEd

далее консольной командой

```
    yii message/extract @app/config/messages.php
```

распаковка и инсерты в соответствующие таблицы.
Все бы ничего, да вот значение в message.translation для всех NULL

Что делать? Куда копать? Какие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего - это ожидаемое поведение команды extract. Она сканирует ваш код и выделяет строки для перевода, но не дополняя перевод. Вам надо дописать его самим